# pyqt5: cannot display images in more than one "qlabel" at the same time

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

pyqt5: cannot display images in more than one "qlabel" at the same time.
The program shows no error, but in the function associated with
clicked.connect(self.one_click_detection), the second setPixmap doesn't respond.

```
def one_click_detection(self):
    if self.image_name != '':
        detection_remote_client(mode="one_click_detection", img_path=self.image_name)
        time.sleep(2)
        
        image1 = QtGui.QPixmap(
            os.path.join('../data/car_detection/', 'car_detection_' + os.path.basename(self.image_name))).scaled(
            self.ui.image_car_detection.width(), self.ui.image_car_detection.height())
        self.ui.image_car_detection.setPixmap(image1)
        self.ui.image_car_detection.setScaledContents(True)
        
        image2 = QtGui.QPixmap(
            os.path.join('../data/car_components_detection/', 'car_components_detection_' + os.path.basename(self.image_name))).scaled(
            self.ui.image_car_components_detection.width(), self.ui.image_car_components_detection.height())
        self.ui.image_car_components_detection.setPixmap(image2)
        self.ui.image_car_components_detection.setScaledContents(True)

        image3 = QtGui.QPixmap(
            os.path.join('../data/car_components_recognition/', 'car_components_recognition_' + os.path.basename(self.image_name))).scaled(
            self.ui.image_car_components_recognition.width(), self.ui.image_car_components_recognition.height())
        self.ui.image_car_components_recognition.setPixmap(image3)
        self.ui.image_car_components_recognition.setScaledContents(True)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Besides, you should *not* use blocking functions like `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.